# How to display variable values in resultset

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I am unable to transform below T-SQL script to ORACLE.

```
DECLARE @ABC VARCHAR(50) = 'SOME VALUE'
SELECT @ABC
```

Comment: select cast('SOME VALUE' as VARCHAR(50)) from dual?

Comment: It must have DECLARE statement.

Comment: @PratapMane Don't just post something and expect someone to convert the code for you. Explain your requirement. Post the input and desired output.

Comment: output should be in DATAGRID not in DBMS OUTPUT.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working in SQL and would like to return the result-set return like in T-SQL you can use SP with out sys_refcursor parameter at Oracle side. The result-set in such a case can be returned and processed in various ways. Please follow the example below for one of the solutions:

```
create or replace  procedure sp_ret_res_set(ref1 out sys_refcursor)
is
v_ABC VARCHAR2(50) DEFAULT 'SOME VALUE';
begin
open ref1 for select v_ABC from dual;
end;
/
var c refcursor;
/
execute sp_ret_res_set(:c);
/
print c;
```

Comment: I do not want to print message. I need it in resultset.

Comment: Then you need a sys_refcursor

Comment: I agree with @IspirerSQLWaysMigrations  for using sys_refcursor . If still you don't want to use sys_refcursor then i would recommend to use Oracle TYPES.

Comment: @IspirerSQLWaysMigrations code does not result anything. Looking for Oracle TYPES if it satisfies my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need a plain **SELECT**.

For example,

```
SQL> SELECT CAST('SOME VALUE' AS VARCHAR(50)) str FROM dual;

STR
--------------------------------------------------
SOME VALUE

SQL>
```

You could directly use the **DUAL** table without explicitly casting to VARCHAR2,

```
SQL> SELECT 'SOME VALUE' str FROM dual;

STR
----------
SOME VALUE

SQL>
```

However, if you do not explicitly cast it, it would be **CHAR** and not **VARCHAR2**. So, if you want the datatype to be VARCHAR2, then use **CAST**.